# Is this incorrect use of std::bind or a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, mingw

I am using the latest snapshot build of clang with latest TDM-Gcc headers and libs. When compiling this (using -std=c++11 flag):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        void Bar(int x)
        {
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    auto f = std::bind(&Foo::Bar, &foo, 5);
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

I get these errors:

```
In file included from Test.cpp:1:
C:\DevEnv\LLVM38\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional:1426:7: error: static_assert failed "Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to-member"
      static_assert(_Varargs::value
      ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\DevEnv\LLVM38\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional:1440:7: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::_Bind_check_arity<void (Foo::*)(int) __attribute__((thiscall)), Foo *, int>' requested here
    : _Bind_check_arity<typename decay<_Func>::type, _BoundArgs...>
      ^
C:\DevEnv\LLVM38\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional:1461:5: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Foo::*)(int) __attribute__((thiscall)), Foo *, int>' requested here
    _Bind_helper<__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs...>::type
    ^
Test.cpp:16:14: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'bind' [with _Func = void (Foo::*)(int) __attribute__((thiscall)), _BoundArgs = <Foo *, int>]
    auto f = std::bind(&Foo::Bar, &foo, 5);
             ^
Test.cpp:16:14: error: no matching function for call to 'bind'
    auto f = std::bind(&Foo::Bar, &foo, 5);
             ^~~~~~~~~
C:\DevEnv\LLVM38\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional:1490:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Result'
    bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
    ^
C:\DevEnv\LLVM38\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\functional:1462:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Func = void (Foo::*)(int) __attribute__((thiscall)), _BoundArgs = <Foo *, int>]
    bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Am i misusing std::bind or is this some weird compiler error? It seems to compile fine using just TDM Gcc.

Comment: So i suppose its a clang bug?

Comment: I wouldn't hurry to call bug that fast. Check your enviroment, I [believe](http://ideone.com/pTM1cN) there might be something off there.

Comment: Works fine for me with Clang 3.6.2.

Comment: I just made some fresh installs with the versions i mentioned above, after observing this behavior on the stable 3.6.2 clang build

Comment: @5gonq2eder On windows? With what gcc accompanied?

Comment: Parabola GNU/Linux, Clang 3.6.2, GCC 5.2.0.

Comment: Well i got this problem on windows..

Comment: it builds and runs fine for me with clang-3.6, gcc 4.8.4, on linux mint. TheArtist: maybe you need to use clang libstdc++ with clang rather than the gcc standard headers and libs? I think that could make a difference.

Comment: Well clang's windows implementation to libstdc++ is not even closed to finished...

Comment: It works for me even with Clang using the GCC headers in case this wasn't already clear.

Comment: Excellent testcase (aside from the redundant `return 0` taking up space :P)

Comment: @5gon12eder yes but does it work on Windows and with what versions? Cause you said about compilation on linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This code is fine.**

Unless you've done something weird or unsupported with your installation, your toolchain has a bug.

To me it looks like it's not considering the second argument to `std::bind` to be the "this pointer", and thinks you're actually passing two arguments to `Foo::Bar` (which you're not), which you can't.

<strike>The next step is to raise this with the maintainers of your toolchain.</strike>

See https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24372.

Comment: [It already was reported](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24372).
It happens to me only with mingw32 headers and Clang x86, but it works fine with mingw64 headers and Clang x64.